# Python string comparison not working for matching lines

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a small Python script to generate CentOS7 kickstart configs. I have a skeleton config file and based on some user inputs, the script will pop out a custom cfg file by inserting the customized blocks into the skeleton. However, the string comparison is not working for some reason.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

type = raw_input("Static OR DHCP: ")
gateway = raw_input("Gateway IP: ")
nameserver = raw_input("DNS Server: ")
hostname = raw_input("Hostname: ")
ipaddr = raw_input("IP Address: ")

skeleton = open('ks_skeleton.cfg', 'r')
config = open(hostname + '.cfg', 'w')

for line in skeleton:
        if line == "$NETWORK":
                print("Interting Network values...");
                config.write("network  --bootproto=" + type + " --device=ens192 --gateway=" + gateway + " --ip=" + ipaddr + " --nameserver=" + nameserver + " --netmask=255.255.255.0 --ipv6=auto --activate\n");
                config.write("network  --hostname=" + hostname + "\n");
        else:
                config.write(line);
```

Comment: "Not working" in what way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lines that you read from `skeleton` have new lines at the end, so the exact string comparison are probably not going to work.  If you do `line = line.strip()` as the first line of your loop it will remove whitespace from before and after any text on the line, and might get you closer to what you want.

Comment: Alternatively, `if line == "$NETWORK\n":`.

Comment: And if you want to keep any whitespace, and just strip the newlines, `line = line.strip('\n')`